# CKEditor Custom Build Package Errors

Tags: reactjs, ckeditor

I have a custom build of CKEditor using their online builder tool. I moved the custom build into the root of my React project and installed all the dependencies. I have a basic implementation of the CKEditor (below). While the core functionality of the editor will work, the following error is thrown and several plugins for the editor do not work. If I remove the config property, the error goes away, but some of the plugins still fail to work. I'm stuck with where to even start to trouble shoot the error and curious if anyone else has run into similar issues.

```
ERROR
Cannot read properties of null (reading 'model')
TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'model')
    at http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:81059:41
```

```
import { CKEditor } from "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-react";
import { Box } from "@mui/material";
import Editor from "ckeditor5-custom-build/build/ckeditor";

type Props = {
  value: string;
  handleChange: ({ value, name }: { value: string; name: string }) => void;
  styles?: any;
  name: string;
};

export default function RichTextEditor({
  value,
  handleChange,
  styles,
  name,
}: Props) {
  return (
    <Box sx={styles}>
      <CKEditor
        editor={Editor}
        data={value}
        config={{
          cloudServices: {
            uploadUrl: "https://100822.cke-cs.com/easyimage/upload/",
            tokenUrl:
              "https://100822.cke-cs.com/token/dev/61cdd746b079eb36b7afc66cb5f81ab90f46d9e4fb0d6de71df6b156b7fb?limit=10",
          },
        }}
        onChange={(event, editor) => {
          handleChange({ value: editor.getData(), name: name });
        }}
      />
    </Box>
  );
}
```